# Why and when do I need to follow a method name with _?

Tags: scala, partial-application

I'm a bit shaky on the rules as to when you need a `_` after a method to use it as a function. For example, why is there a difference between `Foo`'s and `Nil`'s `::` in the following?

```
def square(n: Int) = n * n  
object Foo { def ::(f: Int => Int) = f(42) }

// ...

scala> Foo.::(square)
res2: Int = 1764

scala> Nil.::(square) 
<console>:6: error: missing arguments for method square in object $iw;
follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function
   Nil.::(square)
          ^
scala> Nil.::(square _) 
res3: List[(Int) => Int] = List(<function1>)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you omit all parameters in a partially applied function expression, then you need to follow it with `_` *unless* the compiler *requires* a function type in the place where you use it.

When you call the method `::` on `Foo`, the compiler expects a type `Int => Int` for the parameter. So you can safely omit the underscore after `square` in that position.

However, the `::` method on `Nil` can take a parameter of *any* type. So rather than assume that you meant to partially apply the function, it complains unless you make it absolutely explicit by adding `_`.

So those are the rules... I can't really enlighten you about *why* those are the rules; maybe somebody else who has better knowledge of the compiler, the type system, and the language design will be able to tell you why. But I assume that without these rules, there would be a danger of accidental ambiguity in many places.

Comment: Thanks. Just found part of the Scala Language Spec which gives some justification for the "why", in the change notes for Scala 2.0: "The rules for implicit conversions of methods to functions (§6.25) have been tightened. Previously, a parameterized method used as a value was always implicitly converted to a function. This could lead to unexpected results when method arguments where forgotten. Consider for instance the statement below: show(x.toString)..."