# What is the difference between multiple argument lists and returning a function?

Tags: function, scala, partial-application

What is the difference between `def f(x: Int)(y: Int) = x + y` and `def f(x: Int) = (y: Int) => x + y`?

The REPL doesn’t seem happy when I treat the former the same as the latter:

```
scala> def f(x: Int)(y: Int) = x + y
f: (x: Int)(y: Int)Int

scala> f(42)
<console>:9: error: missing arguments for method f;
follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function
              f(42)
               ^

scala> def f(x: Int) = (y: Int) => x + y
f: (x: Int)Int => Int

scala> f(42)
res2: Int => Int = <function1>
```

What are the exact differences and when should I use which form?

Comment: Well, one is a function with two arguments and one returns a function that takes one argument. No?

Comment: The way I like to think of it is that the first is a method with two unary arglists returning an `Int` (so the result of `f(0)` is still a method `(y: Int)Int`) whereas the latter is a method with one unary arglist returning a unary function `Int => Int`. This explains why only the former complains of the missing underscore; `f(0)` in this case does not evaluate to a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is

```
def f(x: Int)(y: Int) = x + y
```

is a curried function. A function with two parameterlists. You can use it with just one argument, but you need to specify which one.

```
f(42) _ // this is short for f(42)(_: Int)
```

will generate a partial applied function, where the value of `x` is `42`. You could also do:

```
f(_: Int)(42) // note: the first parameter must be used this way
```

This will set the value of `y` to `42`.

Calling a curried function with just a few parameters will generate a partial applied function.

```
def f(x: Int) = (y: Int) => x + y
```

is a partial applied function. Here you have a function which takes one argument and returns a function which takes an argument itself.

Answer (score 1):

With first syntax, you need to add `_` as suggested by the compiler

```
scala> f(42) _
res1: Int => Int = <function1>
```

cf : [Why and when do I need to follow a method name with _?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064193/why-and-when-do-i-need-to-follow-a-method-name-with/2064274#2064274)